# QnAMaker QnA format support

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I have not been able to use the auto import for QnAMaker successfully for several, differently-formatted, docx and sharepoint-based web faqs.

I see support for TSV called out in several places and wonder if there are examples of working docx formatted documents or web page formats that work?

The help content provided with qnamkaer states that markdown is supported. I am also seeking a guide to specific syntax supported.

Answer (score 0):

The [QnAMaker FAQ](https://qnamaker.ai/Documentation/Faqs) states that it should work with this format:

```
.txt, .docx, .pdf: QnA contained as regular FAQ content, i.e. sequence of questions and answers.
```

I got it to work with a .txt file; Just start with a question followed by the answer. Seperate them with a comma and a space, just like a normal sentence (i.e. as shown in the above example). Start a new question on a new line. Easy as that.